# (Xamarin Forms) Can replace library "TEditor" to replace orther library?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm using `Xamarin forms` version 3.6, I want replace lib `[TEditor][1]` with a library similar it.

Do you have third party or library as same as with it on `Xamarin Forms`?

Please help me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, maybe we can help you descrive why TEditor is not good for you and what features you are lookin for.

Btw, you can try this:
https://github.com/enesdalga/XamarinHtmlEditor

Or this:
https://github.com/TimPurdum/RichTextEditor